# jquery dataTables binding

Tags: datatables

I'm using jQuery Datatable plugin for grid purposes. When I click on a row in the grid, I want to bind the details of the row to an input on the same page depending on the ID stored in the row. Can you provide me with a row clickevent? Below is my code. When I click on a row in I get the following error "Bind value for element: expenseList.value must be a simple value. Element not found: ID"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
        <title>Mo Rentals using CFGRID</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dataTableStyles.css" /> 
        <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        $(document).ready( function () { $('#expenseList').dataTable(); } );

    </head>

    <body>
Filter From: To:
Date    Machine     Operator Name   Income  Expenditure     Profit  
image   #DATEFORMAT(results.hireDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")#    #results.machineNumber#     #results.fullname#  UGX #NumberFormat(results.revenue, ',')#    UGX #NumberFormat(results.expense, ',')#    UGX #NumberFormat(results.subTotal, ',')#   image

    <cfform> Distance Moved: <cfinput type="text" name="distanceMoved" id="distanceMoved" readonly="true"> </cfform>

// The plugin function for adding a new filtering routine 
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push( 
    function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex)
    { 
        var dateStart = parseDateValue($("#dateStart").val());
        var dateEnd = parseDateValue($("#dateEnd").val()); 
        // aData represents the table structure as an array of columns, so the script access the date value
        // in the first column of the table via aData[0] 
        var evalDate= parseDateValue(aData[1]); 
        if (evalDate >= dateStart && evalDate <= dateEnd) { return true; } else { return false; } 
    }); 
// Function for converting a mm/dd/yyyy date value into a numeric string for comparison (example 08/12/2010 becomes 20100812 
function parseDateValue(rawDate) { 
    var dateArray= rawDate.split("/"); 
    var parsedDate= dateArray[2] + dateArray[0] + dateArray[1]; 
    return parsedDate;
} 
$(function() 
{
    // Implements the dataTables plugin on the HTML table 
    var $dTable= $("table.dataTablesTable").dataTable( { "iDisplayLength": 200, "bStateSave": false, "oLanguage": { "sLengthMenu": 'Show <select>2550100200 entries' }, "aaSorting": [[0,'asc']], "aoColumns": [ { "sType": "date" }, null, null ] }); 
    // The dataTables plugin creates the filtering and pagination controls for the table dynamically, so these 
    // lines will clone the date range controls currently hidden in the baseDateControl div and append them to 
    // the feedbackTable_filter block created by dataTables $dateControls= 
    $("#baseDateControl").children("div").clone(); 
    $("#feedbackTable_filter").prepend($dateControls); 
    // Implements the jQuery UI Datepicker widget on the date controls
    $('.datepicker').datepicker( {showOn: 'button', buttonImage: 'assets/dateIcon.png', buttonImageOnly: true} ); 
    // Create event listeners that will filter the table whenever the user types in either date range box or 
    // changes the value of either box using the Datepicker pop-up calendar 
    $("#dateStart").keyup ( function() { $dTable.fnDraw(); } ); 
    $("#dateStart").change( function() { $dTable.fnDraw(); } ); 
    $("#dateEnd").keyup ( function() { $dTable.fnDraw(); } ); 
    $("#dateEnd").change( function() { $dTable.fnDraw(); } ); 
});

<cfajaxproxy bind="javascript:getExpense({expenseList@click})"> <cfajaxproxy cfc="CFCs.crud" jsclassname="dataproxy">
function getExpense() { var ID = ColdFusion.getElementValue("ID") if(isNaN(ID)) return dataService.getExpense(ID) } function showData(d) { //convert into a struct var data = {} for(var i=0; i < d.COLUMNS.length; i++) { data[d.COLUMNS[i]] = d.DATA[0][i] } document.getElementById('distanceMoved').value = data["distanceMoved"] } var dataService = new dataproxy() dataService.setCallbackHandler(showData)

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I added a little formatting, but you need to go in and clean it up.  Make sure you leave at least 4 spaces in front of all your code lines, so it stays in the code block.

Answer (score 0):

Events are given for Rows in Datatables. Click [Here](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html) for examples

Comment: i have tried that but nothing happens. Could anyone help me out here on how exactly to get it working?

Comment: Hi Aaron, this is what i have so far        <script type="text/javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready( function () {
     
  $('#expenseList').DataTable(); 
 
  $('#expenseList tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
         var name = $('td', this).eq(0).text();
         alert( 'You clicked on '+name+'\'s row' );
     } );  
 
 } );
</script>

Comment: Still trying to get this to work but am stuck... someone please help me

Comment: Post your code in a readable manner, what is the error message? can you reproduce the problem?